# DHCP request library

Tags: python, linux, dhcp

Currently, I am using "subprocess" command with "dhclient" so I can make DHCP request from server. I am trying to improve that and just use a pure python library to make DHCP client request. Any one know a library can do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out pydhcplib, see a usage example at http://pydhcplib.tuxfamily.org/pmwiki/index.php?n=Site.ClientExample

EDIT: gave it a try on my Ubuntu 12.04

installation:

```
$ cd pydhcplib-0.6.2/
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

test.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from pydhcplib.dhcp_packet import *
from pydhcplib.dhcp_network import *


netopt = {'client_listen_port':68,
       'server_listen_port':67,
       'listen_address':"0.0.0.0"}


class Client(DhcpClient):
    def __init__(self, options):
         DhcpClient.__init__(self,options["listen_address"],
                        options["client_listen_port"],
                        options["server_listen_port"])

    def HandleDhcpOffer(self, packet):
        print packet.str()
    def HandleDhcpAck(self, packet):
        print packet.str()
    def HandleDhcpNack(self, packet):
        print packet.str()        

client = Client(netopt)
# Use BindToAddress if you want to emit/listen to an internet address (like 192.168.1.1)
# or BindToDevice if you want to emit/listen to a network device (like eth0)
client.BindToAddress()

while True :
    print client.GetNextDhcpPacket()
```

Run it:

```
$ sudo python x.py 
# Header fields
op : BOOTREPLY
htype : 1
hlen : 6
hops : 0
xid : 2381790907
secs : 0
flags : 0
ciaddr : 0.0.0.0
yiaddr : 192.168.125.88
siaddr : 0.0.0.0
giaddr : 0.0.0.0
chaddr : 60:fa:cd:bb:25:a5
sname : 
file : 
# Options fields
server_identifier : 3232267521
subnet_mask : 255.255.255.0
domain_name_server : 66.234.224.2 - 8.8.8.8 - 
router : 192.168.125.1 - 
dhcp_message_type : DHCP_ACK
ip_address_lease_time : 86400

# Header fields
op : BOOTREPLY
htype : 1
hlen : 6
hops : 0
xid : 3920377619
secs : 0
flags : 32768
ciaddr : 192.168.125.138
yiaddr : 192.168.125.138
siaddr : 0.0.0.0
giaddr : 0.0.0.0
chaddr : 68:5d:43:8c:3e:94
sname : 
file : 
# Options fields
server_identifier : 3232267521
subnet_mask : 255.255.255.0
domain_name_server : 66.234.224.2 - 8.8.8.8 - 
router : 192.168.125.1 - 
dhcp_message_type : DHCP_ACK
ip_address_lease_time : 86400
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond.First, Sorry because I am new to python and new to 'stockoverflow' so I might not explain my question very well. The issue now is my wireless adapter 'wlan0' is already associated with my wireless network using 'wpa_supplicant'. However, it needs DHCP request so it can get an IP address. I tried the example you suggested and I changed 'client.BindToAddress()' to 'BindToDevice()' so it should listen to my 'wlan0'. But it keep on listening without doing any thing. I think I am missing something here.

Comment: updated answer accordingly, note that I've added a print to the original example